# Removing copyright notice in UIs of Apache 2 licensed software

Tags: licensing, apache-2.0, license-notice

I am customizing a  particular software developed by Company X and distributed with Apache 2 license. I expect to use my customized version for commercial  purpose. The original software comes with a user interface and it has the copy write notice with company name as bellow.

```
X security manager | ©2017 X inc.
```

Does Apache 2 license allow removing above line and add anything else ?

Comment: Do you ask if you can remove (as in title) or if you can add to the copyright notice (as in the question body)?

Answer (score 7):

You must not misrepresent the copyright ownership of the software. Therefore, you cannot remove a copyright notice, or replace it with your name. The original authors still hold the copyright to their work.

When you make changes to the software, the copyright of the software is shared between you and the original authors. You can therefore add a notice for your copyright, for example:

```
Copyright 2017 Your Name
Copyright 2017 Original Authors
```

While you should not remove copyright notices that are shown in the user interface, you can change how these notices are displayed. A menu item called “Help > About this software” is a good place in GUIs, so you could move them there.

The [Apache License 2.0](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) has a couple of terms that are relevant to your scenario.

- You must keep any copyright notices intact in the *source files*, i.e. as part of the copyright headers in each source code file (see 4.c). This suggests (but doesn't explicitly state) that you are not required to keep copyright notices intact in non-source forms of the software, e.g. as part of a GUI. I would still advise against removing existing copyright notices if that would create the fraudulent impression that you would be the sole copyright owner.
- Adding a copyright notice is explicitly allowed in 4.d: “You may add Your own copyright statement to Your modifications”.
- If the original contains a NOTICE file, you must display it in the user interface, “if and wherever such third-party notices normally appear” (from 4.d again). For a GUI, that would probably be an entry in the help menu. Again, adding your own notices is allowed: “You may add Your own attribution notices within Derivative Works that You distribute, alongside or as an addendum to the NOTICE text from the Work” (ibid.).
- Don't forget to give your users a copy of the license (see 4.a).

Comment: Instead of adding your own name, which would eventually lead to a project having *many* near duplicate copyright statements. Is it okay to remove the original author's name and replace it with an entity/group which includes the original author? For instance replacing "Copyright person Y" with "Copyright Contributors to the X Project".

Comment: @AnnanFay Removing existing copyright notices is not OK, and quite illegal in many jurisdictions. But *adding* such a catch-all copyright notice is fine (though legally meaningless since the project X contributors aren't a legal entity holding the copyright). This is actually my preferred solution since it clarifies that there are many copyright holders. There should still be opportunity for individual attributions, e.g. a list of contributors in a NOTICE file.

Comment: @amon By "**adding** such a catch-all", do you mean we are never allowed to fully replace it, not even with a catch-all?

Comment: @Top-Master What is "it" in this context? In general, you must not remove or replace existing copyright notices. You can add your own copyright notices, including such catch-all notices. Removal of an existing copyright notice would be OK e.g. if that author's contributions have also been removed completely, including any derivatives in other places.

Comment: d= (◕‿↼ ) Okay, we wanted to have a single line copyright in our About-dialog (a catch-all), and thought, maybe we are allowed for GUI (but seems we can't replace existing even if it's visual and not some code).

Comment: Oh wait a second, we can remove that entire file, or simply call another method instead, omg!

Answer (score 1):

In general (not just with Apache) you should (or with many licenses, *must*) preserve the existing copyright line, but you can add your own copyright line.
This requirement to preserve the copyright notice is usually included in the license text.

Comment: Is replacing "Copyright person Y" with "Copyright Contributors to the X Project" okay?